# Rewarded Interstitials - How to react to a user cancelling an Ad? (AdMob Google Ads, iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynccallback, admob-rewardedvideoad

I'm implementing `GADRewardedInterstitialAd` into a game.

https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/api/reference/Classes/GADRewardedInterstitialAd

I'm using `presentFromRootViewController:userDidEarnRewardHandler` to react to the user finishing the ad.
Now I'd *also* like to know how to react to the user cancelling the ad.

If I continue directly after calling presentFromRootViewController, the callback handler will not have been called yet, because the systems works asynchonous, as is to be expected. So any game animations (e.g. screen fade, dialog close) will have to be stalled.

If I rely only on the handler, I won't get a callback when the ad was cancelled.

My solution would be to build in a timer that waits 30+1s to give the handler a chance to get called (hopefully on the next main thread dispatch cycle), and then react to it not being called yet (assuming a cancellation by the user).
I really hate that plan.

1. It's not deterministic.
2. It doesn't use callbacks/delegates/handlers (which are great exactly for this kind of thing)
3. I have to write the timer code and keep a boolean flag somewhere... it's messy.
4. It adds an arbitrary delay to the user experience (30+1s) when they close the ad!!

Am I thinking the wrong way about this or is this just the way Google has made it and I'll have to live with it?

**Edit:** please note that I'm talking about the new **GADRewardedInterstitialAd** API, not *GADRewardedAd*.

Answer (score 2):

I've figured it out; it works by setting `GADFullScreenContentDelegate fullScreenContentDelegate` and implementing `adDidDismissFullScreenContent`.

In there you can check if this particular instance of `GADRewardedInterstitialAd` did not get a reward yet (as notified by `userDidEarnRewardHandler`...)

This all hinges on the assertion that `adDidDismissFullScreenContent` gets called AFTER the `userDidEarnRewardHandler`, else I will already have assumed there was no reward. Let's hope that is always the case.

https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/mobile-ads-sdk/ios/api/reference/Protocols/GADFullScreenContentDelegate